# Unexpected valgrind "invalid write" when fstack-check is used

Tags: c, gcc, valgrind

I have the following very simple C program (`test.c`):

```
int f(int i)
{
  return i;
}

int main(int argC, char* argV[])
{
  int x = f(12);
  return 1;
}
```

I have done some tests with valgrind, playing with the `-fstack-check` compiler flag in two different systems.

Test done at **Debian 8.6** with gcc 4.9.2 and valgrind 3.10.0.

Without `-fstack-check`:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==103703== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==103703== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==103703== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==103703== Command: ./test
==103703== 
==103703== 
==103703== HEAP SUMMARY:
==103703==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==103703==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==103703== 
==103703== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==103703== 
==103703== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==103703== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

With `-fstack-check`:

```
$ gcc -fstack-check test.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==103726== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==103726== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==103726== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==103726== Command: ./test
==103726== 
==103726== 
==103726== HEAP SUMMARY:
==103726==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==103726==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==103726== 
==103726== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==103726== 
==103726== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==103726== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Test done in **CentOS 6.6** with gcc 4.4.7 and valgrind 3.8.1:

Without `-fstack-check`:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==16390== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16390== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16390== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16390== Command: ./test
==16390== 
==16390== 
==16390== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16390==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16390==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==16390== 
==16390== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16390== 
==16390== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16390== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

With `-fstack-check`:

```
$ gcc -fstack-check test.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==16441== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16441== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16441== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16441== Command: ./test
==16441== 
==16441== Invalid write of size 8
==16441==    at 0x400497: main (in /home/fermin/valgrindtest/test)
==16441==  Address 0x7feffd058 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==16441== 
==16441== 
==16441== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==16441==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FEFFD058
==16441==    at 0x400497: main (in /home/fermin/valgrindtest/test)
==16441==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==16441==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==16441==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==16441==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==16441==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==16441== 
==16441== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16441==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16441==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==16441== 
==16441== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16441== 
==16441== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16441== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

In this case, in addition, the program ends with segmentation fault.

**In summary**, while in Debian all seems to be ok with `-fstack-check`, in CentOS I'm getting an "Invalid write" error that I'm not able to explain given the code of my program.

Reading about [the `-fstack-check` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Stack-Checking.html) maybe the error trace is due to the stack check mechanism is allocating 8 bytes in heap space for the `x` variable but valgrind (due to some reason) is not able to get aware of that, so it marks it as an invalid write. Maybe this is a limitation in valgrind 3.8.1 that has been solved in 3.10.0 (given the fact that in the Debian setup, using 3.10.0, I'm not getting that trace)?

In addition, I have seem at [valgring FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful) that *"`-fomit-frame-pointer` and `-fstack-check` can make stack traces worse"* but they don't provide too much information about the reason for this so I cannot know if the problem is related...

Any help or hint which helps to explain this is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: as suggested in one comment, I'm including the dissasembled code for the CentOS 6.x case, compiling with `-g3` and using `objdump --source test`. I'm including here the part corresponding to main() and f() functions, however the full dump can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/fgalan/ce18b610a313288fcf3cc79bfd745ec7).

Binary compiled with `-fstack-check`:

```
0000000000400474 <f>:
int f(int i)
{
  400474:   55                      push   %rbp
  400475:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400478:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  return i;
  40047b:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
}
  40047e:   c9                      leaveq 
  40047f:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400480 <main>:

int main(int argC, char* argV[])
{
  400480:   55                      push   %rbp
  400481:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400484:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  400488:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  40048b:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  int x = f(12);
  return 0;
  40048f:   48 8d 84 24 08 d0 ff    lea    -0x2ff8(%rsp),%rax
  400496:   ff 
  400497:   48 c7 00 00 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,(%rax)
  return i;
}

int main(int argC, char* argV[])
{
  int x = f(12);
  40049e:   bf 0c 00 00 00          mov    $0xc,%edi
  4004a3:   e8 cc ff ff ff          callq  400474 <f>
  4004a8:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  return 0;
  4004ab:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  4004b0:   c9                      leaveq 
  4004b1:   c3                      retq
```

Binary compiled without `-fstack-check`:

```
0000000000400474 <f>:
int f(int i)
{
  400474:   55                      push   %rbp
  400475:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400478:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  return i;
  40047b:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
}
  40047e:   c9                      leaveq 
  40047f:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400480 <main>:

int main(int argC, char* argV[])
{
  400480:   55                      push   %rbp
  400481:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400484:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  400488:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  40048b:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  int x = f(12);
  40048f:   bf 0c 00 00 00          mov    $0xc,%edi
  400494:   e8 db ff ff ff          callq  400474 <f>
  400499:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  return 0;
  40049c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  4004a1:   c9                      leaveq 
  4004a2:   c3                      retq
```

**EDIT2:** I have tested with newest valgrind version at the present moment (3.13.0) in CentOS 6.8 and I get the same problem.

Comment: Did you checked the behavior if you change the return value of main i.e. any value other than `1`?

Comment: I have tried also with `return 0` and `return 2` and the result in CentOS 6.6 with `-fstack-check` is the same (i.e. "Invalid write"). Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: can you paste the dissasembled code ?

Comment: @alinsoar, I have just edited the question post to add dissasembled code. I'm not an expert in x86 assembler, so if you find something wrong in the way I've generated it, please tell me. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: it is ok so, for more useful info can you dissasemble it with ``objdump --souce test`` and compile the test.c with the `-gdwarf` and `-g3` flags ?

Comment: Trying `gcc -fstack-check -gdwarf -g3 test.c -o test` I get `cc1: error: unrecognised debug output level "dwarf"`. Maybe that flag is not supported in gcc 4.4.7?

Comment: Does Valgrind 3.13 show the same behaviour?

Comment: @PaulFloyd, unfortunatelly I don't have access to systems with valgrind 3.13 installed, only 3.10.0 and 3.8.1. However, I'll try to set one and provide feedback editing the question post.

Comment: @fgalan You can't download and build your own copy of Valgrind?

Comment: @alinsoar, replacing dissasembled code with the one using `--source` and `-g3`.

Comment: @PaulFloyd, test done with valgrind 3.13.0. Same result :(. See EDIT2 mark in the question post.

Comment: Two obvious things 1.The program is demonstrably correct. 2. The compiler release you are using is rather old and bugs in it probably won't be fixed (4.4.7 is the last release in the 4.4 series and it's 5 years old). Decide for yourself if it's worth your time.

Comment: @n.m. I have done a quick test with gcc 4.7.2 and I think you are right. I've self-answered by question. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I have installed gcc 4.7.2 in my CentOS 6.6 system (using [this procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos)) and re-done the test compiling with `-fstack-check`:

```
$ /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc -fstack-check test.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==19374== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19374== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19374== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19374== Command: ./test
==19374== 
==19374== 
==19374== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19374==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19374==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==19374== 
==19374== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19374== 
==19374== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19374== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Note that now the "invalid write" error is not shown. Thus, it seems that is a problem in the gcc compiler, some kind of bug fixed between 4.4.7 and 4.7.2, as @n.m. suggested in the comments.